# Не работает проверка $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] на сервере

Tags: php, openserver, postman

Всем привет!
На Open Server использую проверку:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
   echo "Failed!";
else
   echo "Success!";
```

При отправке данных в Postman на локальном сервере (Open Server) проверка проходит корректно, на сервере хостера с теми же данными не проходит. Версии php и php.ini одинаковые на обоих серверах. Что-то в настройках сервера, но не могу понять что. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

UPD: Прикрепляю дамп $_SERVER:

```
array(36) {
["PATH"]=>
string(60) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(14) "/api/index.php"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(14) "/api/index.php"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
string(0) ""
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
string(3) "GET"
["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
string(8) "HTTP/1.0"
["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
string(7) "CGI/1.1"
["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
string(5) "47956"
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
string(65) "/var/www/u0699445/data/www/host.com/api/index.php"
["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
string(20) "hello@host.com"
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
string(41) "/var/www/u099876/data/www/host.com"
["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
string(13) "95.44.22.332"
["SERVER_PORT"]=>
string(3) "443"
["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
string(9) "127.0.0.1"
["SERVER_NAME"]=>
string(24) "host.com"
["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
string(22) "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)"
["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
string(86) "<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at host.com Port 443</address>
"
["HTTP_REFERER"]=>
string(45) "http://host.com/api/index.php"
["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
string(17) "gzip, deflate, br"
["HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN"]=>
string(36) "a454554a3-4eae-4b1a-ffg45-8d256454g0d39"
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
string(3) "*/*"
["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
string(21) "PostmanRuntime/7.26.2"
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
string(5) "close"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"]=>
string(3) "443"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]=>
string(5) "https"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=>
string(13) "95.79.132.184"
["HTTP_HOST"]=>
string(24) "host.com"
["PERL5LIB"]=>
string(49) "/usr/share/awstats/lib:/usr/share/awstats/plugins"
["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
string(24) "XxwDVsdsdsd0AAAzererDAACC"
["HTTPS"]=>
string(2) "on"
["FCGI_ROLE"]=>
string(9) "RESPONDER"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(14) "/api/index.php"
["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
float(1595671380.5536)
["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
int(1595671380)
["argv"]=>
array(0) {
}
["argc"]=>
int(0)
}
```

Comment: Прикрепите дамп переменной $_SERVER на сервере (var_dump)

Comment: Прикрепил. ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" почему-то GET, хотя в Postman выставлен POST.

Comment: Postman иногда глючит, а так же кэширует запросы и ответы. Попробуйте перезагрузить его, либо сделать запрос через другие приложения типа CURL.

Comment: Перезапустил и сделал через CURL. Результат аналогичный. Попробую написать хостеру, может быть нужно поменять настройки с их стороны.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была банальна. Я использовал http, а нужно было https.